# How to fix multiple ion-content in my Ionic 4 apps

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building a monitoring apps which can display the percentage number. The apps is running fine but after i compile it into an apk file using the command "ionic cordova run android", the home page of my apps divide into 4 parts where each part is the same ion-content. There is only one ion-content code inside my html file. Can anyone help me?

I m using ionic 4.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <div>
    <ion-title>
      IoT Garbage Monitoring System
    </ion-title>
      </div>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding *ngFor="let item of todos">

      <circle-progress
      [percent]= item.bin1
      [radius]="100"
      [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
      [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
      [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
      [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
      [animation]="true"
      [animationDuration]="0"
      [startFromZero]="false"
      [titleFontSize]="55"
      [unitsFontSize]="55"
      [showSubtitle]="true"
      [subtitle]="'bin1'"
  ></circle-progress>

</ion-content>
```

[image]

Comment: Try moving *ngFor="let item of todos" into circle-progress and not on ion-content

Comment: `"There is only one ion-content code inside my html file"`... **no** there isn't. There are as many `ion-content` as you have items in your array as you are adding `ion-content` on each iteration. Moving the iteration down to the `circle-progress` should solve it, like mentioned by Chris.

Comment: use ion-item and put there *ngFor="let item of todos" or you can use div